# Unable to upgrade gradle version in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android studio 2.1.1 with gradle current version - 2.10.

I am trying to upgrade gradle version to 2.14.1, for which I have done the following:

In `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14-all.zip
```

In `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.12'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Upon syncing, I get the following error:

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.14.1.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.14.1/gradle-2.14.1.pom
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.14.1/gradle-2.14.1.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.14.1/gradle-2.14.1.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.14.1/gradle-2.14.1.jar
Required by:
    :MultiPanePlayer:unspecified
```

My project-level settings has the following option "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)" selected. Am I missing anything else ?

Comment: Try `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2` for the compile

Comment: update some details, please check

Comment: Dont' confuse gradle the build tool with the android gradle plugin. They have different version numbers. You want plugin version 2.1.2

Comment: Just realised that, thankyou

Comment: can anyone say what to do im new to android studio...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Error with gradle plugin not getting updated resolved - If you are getting this error you should update the plugin version to 2.1.2 as @Henry has mentioned or 2.3.1. (Be careful it is 2.1.2 and not not 2.12). Here is the sample project level build.gradle that resolved my error-

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```